# ckEditor - setEditorHtmlFilter - Div Styles Ignored

Tags: ckeditor

I am using ckEditor to enable the user to configure HTML snippets that get used by my program as text templates. I have found a problem if styles are not explicitly set by the user in the ckEditor then when my program uses the HTML snippets. I want to allow the user to configure default styles that will be applied to div, span and paragraph elements if the user does not set an explicit style. I have found that I can do this using the code shown below.

```
function setEditorHtmlFilter(editor) {
    var fontSize = "12pt";
    var fontFamily = "arial,helvetica,sans-serif";
    var lineHeight = "1.15";

    editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
        elements: {
            p: function(e) {
                if (!e.attributes.style) {
                    e.attributes.style = "font-size:" + fontSize + ";font-family:" + fontFamily + ";line-height:" + lineHeight + ";";
                }
            },
            span: function(e) {
                if (!e.attributes.style) {
                    e.attributes.style = "font-size:" + fontSize + ";font-family:" + fontFamily + ";line-height:" + lineHeight + ";";
                }
            },
            div: function (e) {
                if (!e.attributes.style) {
                    e.attributes.style = "font-size:" + fontSize + ";font-family:" + fontFamily + ";line-height:" + lineHeight + ";";
                }
            }
        }

    }, {
        applyToAll: true
    });
}
```

My problem is that ckEditor ignores the style added to the containing div in the editor. For example the following div styles are ignored by the editor:

```
<div style="font-size:12pt;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:1.15;">abc</div>

<div style="font-size:12pt;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:1.15;">def</div>

<div style="font-size:12pt;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:1.15;">ghi</div>
```

In my ckEditor config.js I have the following setting:

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV;
```

How can I get the editor to stop ignoring the styles set on the divs?

Answer (score 1):

ckeditor creates its own style in `<div>` container so your style will be ignored but you can use class and external css with `!important` to give it a custom style. with `!important` you external css property will apply and inline css property created by ckeditor will be ignored

**HTML**

```
<div class="custom_div">abc</div>

<div class="custom_div">def</div>

<div class="custom_div">ghi</div>
```

Supposing you need to set black background color

**CSS**

```
.custom_div{
  background:#000 !important;
  /* all other css you want to apply*/
}
```